# Composer PSR-4 Autoload Interface Deprecation Notice

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phar

I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with this simple interface.

```
<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

use Illuminate\View\View;

interface renderData
{
        public function renderAsHtml(): View;
}
```

When I `composer dump-autoload` i receive the following notice

> Deprecation Notice: Class App\Interfaces\renderData located in ./app/Interfaces/RenderData.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0.

composer.json autoload part:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
     },
```

Folder structure is:

```
<root_project>
 app
 Console
 ...
```

I have already try to rename app to App then dump-autoload but the problem persist.

Comment: can edit the post and you share `autoload` part of your `composer.json` ? Also what is the folder structure of this class ?

Comment: Done, i think it's the 'App' 'app' problem...

Comment: Check for case-sensitive file and class names - you've named your file `RenderData.php` with a capital `R`, but your interface uses a lower-cased `r`

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase
Typo on my side. I was wondering why all the others were working and this specific interface was throwing a warning. Since I always follow a standard, I had not paid attention to the namings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be that  first letter of ‘app’ folder is in small case in app/Interfaces/RenderData’, but in the namespace is in upper case in ‘App\Interfaces’.

Make sure the folder structure and naming matches namespace.

Comment: Yes, it could be but how can I fix it? I've added new informations to the main thread.

Comment: Capitalize the app folder in you project directory.

Comment: Either rename folder from `app\` to `App\\`, i.e. capitalize it,
Either rename interface from `App\Interfaces` to `app\Interfaces`, i.e. make it lower case.

Comment: Why does App\Models works but we have to use app\... for our code?

Answer (score 5):

This is the main reason for `composer`'s latest version.

Check your composer version using

```
composer -V
```

Install another version using

```
composer self-update 1.6.3
```

and delete the vendor folder from your project.

And use the following commands:

```
composer install
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

Hope it will work.